# How to save data on different database tables in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

how to save the data from the Features fields on a different table. Example in the link below, it is saving the Features table fields in a JSON field in the database. However, I want to save this data from the features into another table.

https://demo.backpackforelavel.com/admin/product/211/Edit

[image]

I'm coming back here to post my answer. I managed to settle, I'm putting here to help other developers.

This first part of the question I have already solved. But now I can not bring the data from the Features fields in the form.

Below is the source code that I was able to save and edit the form data. However, I can not carry the data from the Feature fields. Someone knows how I can carry the field data in Feature

```php
class ProductCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use ListOperation;
    use CreateOperation {
        store as traitStore;
    }
    use UpdateOperation {
        update as traitUpdate;
    }
    use DeleteOperation;

    public function store()
    {
        // insert item in the db
        $item = $this->crud->create($this->crud->getRequest()->except(['save_action', '_token', '_method']));

        $features = json_decode($this->crud->getRequest()->input('features'));

        foreach ($features  as $itens) {
            $obj = new Feature();
            $obj->product_id = $item->getKey();
            $obj->name = $itens->name;
            $obj->save();
        }

        // show a success message
        \Alert::success(trans('backpack::crud.insert_success'))->flash();

        return redirect('admin/product');
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $featureForm = json_decode($this->crud->getRequest()->input('features'));

        // insert item in the db
        $item = $this->crud->update($this->crud->getRequest()->id, $this->crud->getRequest()->except(['save_action', '_token', '_method', 'features']));

        $objF = Feature::where('product_id', $item->getKey())->get();

        foreach ($objF as $itens) {
            Feature::where('id', $itens->id)->delete();
        }

        foreach ($featureForm as $itens) {
            $obj = new Feature;
            $obj->product_id = $item->getKey();
            $obj->name = $itens->name;
            $obj->save();
        }

        // show a success message
        \Alert::success(trans('backpack::crud.insert_success'))->flash();

        return redirect('admin/product');
    }
}
```

I'm coming back here to post my answer. I managed to settle, I'm putting here to help other developers.

I was able to bring the data in the form edition, in the Features fields. I used the Mutators in the Model - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Below is the example I did.

It would be interesting to have an example of this in the official documentation or demo project. I believe it would help a lot also to other developers.

```php
    //model Product
    public function getFeaturesAttribute($value)
    {
        $objects = Features::where('product_id', $this->id)->get();
        $array = [];
        foreach ($objects as $itens) {
            $obj = new stdClass;
            $obj->name = $itens->name;
            $array[] = $obj;
        }
        return \json_encode($array);
    }
```

Comment: you can override store method, and save the way you want

Comment: @OMR This first part of the question I have already solved. As you can see, I updated the doubt by adding what you said. But now I can not bring the data from the Features fields in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about it. Personally I prefer to create accessors and mutators in the model - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators . Not only does it keep the CrudController clean (so updateable) but it also allows you to save/load stuff from other forms (ex: user-facing forms).

```php
    //model Product
    public function getFeaturesAttribute($value)
    {
        $objects = Features::where('product_id', $this->id)->get();
        $array = [];
        foreach ($objects as $itens) {
            $obj = new stdClass;
            $obj->name = $itens->name;
            $array[] = $obj;
        }
        return json_encode($array);
    }
```